# A continuous function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is monotonic on $(a,b)$ is also monotonic on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

Let $f:\left  [ a,b \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function all over it's domain.

$f$ is monotonic in $(a,b)$, prove that $f$ is monotonic in $\left  [ a,b \right]$.

The statement is somehow very intuitive but I can't find a way to put a proof to work.

Comment: Please note that the ``general-topology`` tag does not reflect anything about the OP's question *as such*; I added it because I desire some visibility from experienced topologists to verify that a bit of my post is actually correct and not misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ increasing in $(a,b)$, i .e.

for $x, y \in (a,b)$, and $x <y$ :

$ f(x) \le f(y)$

Assume there is a $x \in (a,b)$ s.t.

$f(a) > f(x).$

$f$ continuous in $[a,x]$ .

Intermediate Value Theorem for continuous functions:

Let $u$ be s.t.

$f(a)>u> f(x)$, then there exists

$c \in (a,x)$ with $f(c) =u$.

We have $a < c <x$; where $f(c)>f(x),$

a contradiction.

Comment: We keep choosing the same threads, haha.  Our arguments are essentially isomorphic, with your IVT implicitly expressed in my hyperlinked theorem.

Comment: Kaj.My topology is weak, unfortunately, cannot easily follow your answer. Thanks for your comment.Greetings.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Assume that $f$ is inceasing at $(a,b)$.

Let $c\in(a,b)$.

then, for $n$ great enough,
$$a<a+\frac 1n\le c$$
$$\implies f(a+\frac 1n)\le f(c)$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to +\infty}f(a+\frac 1n)\le f(c)$$
which gives by continuity at $x=a$,

$$f(a)\le f(c).$$

You do the same with $b-\frac 1n.$

Answer (score 2):

You need to show that $f(x) \leq f(y)$ for any $a \leq x < y \leq b$. Take any $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x + \epsilon < y - \epsilon$. Then $x + \epsilon$ and $y - \epsilon$ are in $(a,b)$ so by assumption you have
$$f(y - \epsilon) - f(x +  \epsilon) \geq 0$$
But using continuity of $f$ you can take the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ 
to obtain
$$f(y) - f(x) \geq 0$$
This gives $f(x) \leq f(y)$ as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint / proof outline: Without loss of generality assume $f$ is monotone increasing (the case monotone decreasing is the same). We know that $f$ is monotone increasing on $(a,b)$, so we just want to prove that it is monotone increasing at the points $a$ and $b$. To prove this for the point $a$, we want to show that $f(a) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

In order to show this, assume $f(a) > f(x)$ for some $x > a$. **Using the definition of continuity**, find a point $y$ satisfying $a < y < x$ and $f(y) > f(x)$. Why is this a contradiction?

The fact that $f$ is continuous is what makes this proof work. If $f$ were not continuous, you could set the endpoints $f(a), f(b)$ to be whatever you want. Then $f$ would be monotonic on $(a,b)$ but not $[a,b]$.

Comment: One could do an even broader WLoG and note that the argument for one of the endpoints should be analogous to the other.  Thus it suffices to prove that monotonic on $(a,b)$ implies monotonic on $(a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a topological argument. No epsilon pushing necessary!**

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, which we assume WLOG to be monotone *increasing* on $(a,b)$.  Since $f\Big( [a,b] \Big)$ is the continuous image of a compact set, [it must itself be compact](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact), and in particular bounded ([Heine-Borel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)).  Moreover, the image of $(a,b)$ is contained in the image of $[a,b]$, and because [the continuous image of a connected set is connected](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Connected_Space_is_Connected), we deduce that the image of $(a,b)$ is a bounded, connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$—i.e. it is some interval we'll call $I$.  Note that the hyperlinked fact also tells us that $f(b)$ lies within the closure of $I$.

So what if monotonicity fails at $x=b$?  In other words, letting $s = \text{sup} \Big\{f(x) \ | \ x \in (a,b) \Big\}$, let's see where problems arise if $f(b) = w < s$.  Consider the preimage of the interval $U = (w- \varepsilon, \ w + \varepsilon)$, where $0 < \varepsilon < |s-w|$.  It would look like $f^{-1}(U) = V \cup \ \{b\}$, where $V$ is such that $\{b\}$ is isolated.  Due to this isolated point, $f^{-1}(U)$ cannot be open.  Because $U$ is an open set and $f^{-1}(U)$ is not, $f$ cannot be continuous*.  Thus, continuity forces $f(b) = s$, just as it does $f(a) = \text{inf} \Big\{ f(x) \ | \ x \in (a,b) \Big\}$ by an analogous argument.

---

*We are using the topological definition of continuity, which states that a function $f:X \to Y$ between topological spaces is continuous $\iff$ the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ of every open set $U$ of $Y$ is also open in $X$.  When $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, this definition agrees with the analysis definition.

Comment: P.S. I find topology often yields much easier proofs for analytic theorems. Notably, one can arrive at the intermediate value theorem from "the continuous image of a connected set is connected", and the extreme value theorem from proving that the continuous image of a compact set is compact in a general topological setting (using the open cover definition for compactness) and thereafter invoking [Heine-Borel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem). I just can't stand pushing around epsilons and deltas.

Comment: One could argue that I'm being misleading, sweeping all the hard work under the Heine-Borel rug. However, Pete Clark brought my attention to a technique dubbed "real induction" that can prove statements indexed by a continuum, analogous to standard induction with statements indexed by $\mathbb{N}$. Notably, this technique yields a proof of Heine-Borel a mere FOUR LINES LONG. See theorem $17$, bottom of page $7$ [here](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/realinduction.pdf).

Comment: $[a,b]$ is compact and $f$ is continuous so $f(\,[a,b]\,)$ is compact, hence bounded in $\Bbb R .$  So $f(\,(a,b)\,)$ is bounded also. The modern style is that "$f$ is (monotonic) increasing" means $(x<y\implies f(x)\le f(y)\,).$ With this convention, $f(\,(a,b)\,)$ must be a bounded convex (i.e.connected) subset of $\Bbb R$, that is, a bounded interval, but not necessarily an open interval

Comment: If $f$ is strictly increasing (i.e.$ x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)\,)$ then $f(\,(a,b)\,)$ will be a bounded open interval. In the light of my previous comment, (i) Should we present a proof of this?, and (ii) Do we even need this for the question?

Comment: oh crap, I had "strictly increasing" in my head.  Let me think about how this changes things.  Ugh, I invested too much effort into a wrong interpretation.

Comment: ok, answer to (ii): we do not need this.  But I think the general approach should still work: let's say $f(b) = w < \text{sup}\{f(x) \ | \ x \in (a,b) \}$.  Consider the preimage of the open set $(w- \delta, \ w + \delta)$ for a sufficiently small $\delta$; it should still include $b$ as an isolated point and hence is not open.  Does that sound reasonable?  I'll make an edit tomorrow.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, Fixed!  Really appreciate your feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

Following the  modern convention that "$f$ is increasing on $(a,b)$" means $(a<x<y<b\implies f(x)\le f(y)\,):$

(I).Suppose  $f$ is increasing on $(a,b)$ and (by contradiction) that $f$ is not increasing on $(a,b].$ Then there exists $c\in (a,b)$ with $f(c)>f(b).$ Let $\epsilon= (f(c)-f(b))/2.$ Since $f$ is continuous at $b,$ there exists $\delta \in (0, b-c)$ such that $f(x)<f(b)+\epsilon$ whenever $x\in (b-\delta,b).$ In particular, if $x=b-\delta/2$ then $a<c<x<b$ but $f(x) <f(b)+\epsilon<f(c),$ contrary to $f$ being increasing on $(a,b).$

So $f$ must be increasing on $(a,b].$

(II). If $f$ is decreasing on $(a,b)$  then $(-f)$ is increasing on $(a,b)$ and continuous at $b$, so apply (I) to the function $(-f).$ So $(-f)$ is increasing on $(a,b] ,$ so $f$ is decreasing on $(a,b].$

(III). For $x\in (a,b]$ let  $g(x)=f(b+a-x).$ Then $g$ is monotonic on $(a,b]$ and continuous at $x=b.$ So by (I) and (II), $g$ is monotonic on $(a,b].$ So $f$ is monotonic on $[a,b).$

(IV).$f$ is monotonic on $[a,b)$ and on $(a,b].$ Therefore $f$ is monotonic on $[a,b].$

Remarks. With a small modification to (I) we can show that if $f$ is strictly monotonic on $(a,b)$ then $f$ is strictly monotonic on $[a,b].$

And in either case, observe that it suffices that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ and $x=b,$ but not necessarily continuous on $(a,b).$

Further remarks. We can prove (I), that is, if $f$ is increasing on $(a,b)$ then $f$ is increasing on $(a,b]$ directly rather than by contradiction,using the basic result that if $(y_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a convergent real sequence with $ y_n\le y_{n+1} $ for all $n,$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n\ge y_1.$

We want to show that $\forall x\in (a,b)\,(f(x)\le f(b)\,).$

For $x\in (a,b)$ let $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be an increasing sequence of members of $(a,b)$ with $x_1=x$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=b.$ Let $y_n=f(x_n)$ for each $n.$ Then $y_n\le y_{n+1}$ for all $n.$ Now since $f$ is continuous at $b$ and $x_n\to b$  we have $$f(b)=f(\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=$$ $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n\ge y_1=f(x_1)=f(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Lemma 1: Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying

$\tag 1 A \subset B$
$\tag 2 \forall b\in B \; \;\exists a \in A \text{ such that } b\leq a$

Then $\text{sup}(B) = \text{sup}(A)$.

Lemma 2: Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying

$\tag 3 A \subset B$
$\tag 4 \forall b\in B \; \;\exists a \in A \text{ such that } b\geq a$

Then $\text{inf}(B) = \text{inf}(A)$.

Proposition 3: Let $f:\left  [ a,b \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be monotonically increasing on $(a,b)$ and continuous at $x = a$ and $x = b$. Then

$\tag 5 f(a) = \text{inf}\left(f\text{<}\,(a, b)\,\text{>}\right)$
$\tag 6 f(b) = \text{sup}\left(f\text{<}\,(a, b)\,\text{>}\right)$

Corollary 4: Let $f:\left  [ a,b \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be monotonically increasing on $(a,b)$ and continuous at $x = a$ and $x = b$. If $a \lt x \lt b$ then

$\tag 7 f(a) \le f(x) \le f(b)$

and $f$ is monotonically increasing on $[a,b]$.

Lemma 5: The function $f$ is monotonically increasing if and only if $-f$ is monotonically decreasing.